# SQL PIvot Return Value instead of count

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a SQL pivot query where the return result is the name of the product rather than a '0' or '1' value (I am looking for distinct values instead).

Here is my existing query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
( select
EBA_PROJ_STATUS.PROJECT AS PROJECT,
EBA_PROJ_STATUS.REGION AS REGION,
EBA_PROJ_STATUS_AIS.ONE_DB_PRODUCT_TYPE AS ONE_DB_PRODUCT_TYPE
from EBA_PROJ_STATUS EBA_PROJ_STATUS,
EBA_PROJ_STATUS_AIS EBA_PROJ_STATUS_AIS
where EBA_PROJ_STATUS_AIS.PROJECT_ID=EBA_PROJ_STATUS.ID
)
PIVOT (
COUNT (distinct ONE_DB_PRODUCT_TYPE) FOR (ONE_DB_PRODUCT_TYPE)
IN ('PROD1' as PROD1, 'PROD2' as PROD2, 'PROD3' as PROD3, 'PROD4' as PROD4, 'PROD4' as PROD5)
)
```

This puts each product as the header as PROD1, PROD2, etc. and the values returned at a '0' or a '1'. Is there a way to take the 0s and 1s and have it output as the product string instead?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The product string, which will be the same as the column heading? What about the zeros - show those as null?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole that's correct, the zeros should come back as null. The product string is the same as the column heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an aggregate function of the value itself:

```
...
PIVOT (
MAX (ONE_DB_PRODUCT_TYPE) FOR (ONE_DB_PRODUCT_TYPE)
IN ('PROD1' as PROD1, 'PROD2' as PROD2, 'PROD3' as PROD3, 'PROD4' as PROD4, 'PROD4' as PROD5)
);
```

But that will get you a result like:

```
PROJECT   REGI PROD1 PROD2 PROD3 PROD4 PROD5
--------- ---- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
Project 1 EMEA       PROD2 PROD3            
Project 2 NA   PROD1       PROD3
```

which doesn't seem entirely helpful. You can NVL/coalesce the values in the outer select if you want to show something other than nulls instead of the zeros you have now.

Comment: Thank you very much, just needed that MAX value! This is exactly what I needed to get the data formatted. I have a pivot plugin that will perform the count function for me.